# Published application is showing the wrong name in Task Manager

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I am trying to learn how to deploy an application and I am now testing it with this app. Everything works fine (yay!) except in Task Manager it shows the wrong name of the application. Does anybody know how I can change it? In the screenshot below is a red circle of the title that I would like to change. I am aware that this question has been asked before but I am using .NET 6 which has a different preferences panel meaning old solutions no longer work.

[image: Red circle shows the incorrect name, I would like it to be something else.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the compiler acquires all program's metadata from the `[assembly: ...]` attributes. In **.NET Framework** such attributes are usually defined in the project's `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. In **.NET Core** and latest **.NET 5/6** releases this file is automatically generated in the `obj` directory from the properties defined in the project's `.csproj` file. You can manually edit it and add/modify the corresponding metadata properties.

Usually it looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Title>Project's title</Title>
    <AssemblyName>Executable.Name</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyTitle>The title that actually goes to the Task Manager and executable file properties</AssemblyTitle>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>This is a very important project</Description>
    <Copyright>(c) 2021</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <InformationalVersion>1.0.0 alpha</InformationalVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <ApplicationIcon>Some/Relative/Path/To/Icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Other definitions -->
</Project>
```